# Non-constant cubic spline interval

Tags: numerical-methods, cubics, spline

I have the following Numerical Methods homework question that I am working on.

**Question: The velocity profile of a rocket against time is give as below**
\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
\bf t &   0&  10&      15&      20&      22.5&6  30
\\ \hline
\bf v(t)& 0& 227.04& 362.78& 517.35& 602.92& 901.67
\end{array}

**Using cubic splines (6 data points so all possible cubic splines will be 5) to compute**

**1.    Velocity at t=16 seconds**

**2.    Acceleration at t=21 seconds**

**3.    Distance travelled by rocket between t=23 and t=29.**

Here, the interval "h" between the time values isn't constant, whereas all the examples in my slides and the ones I have found online have a constant h like 0,10,15,20, etc. How do I solve such a question with varying interval? Also, should  part 2 and 3 of the question be done by differentiating and integrating the equations I will find for whatever interval the t value falls in? Should I be using numerical differentiation/integration (it doesn't specify)?

Comment: Your on-line resources apparently didn't include wikipedia, which lists [several cubic spline methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline#Interpolating_a_data_set) (differing in how they pick the tangents at the support points). The first two at least do not require uniform spacing of the supports. As for your other two questions. Yes, you should use the cubic splines, just like the problem says, and no, cubic polynomials are easy to differentiate and integrate. There is no need for numerical methods to do either here. The numerical method was using cubic splines at all.